# Not able to paste file in windows explorer after SetClipboardData

Tags: python, winapi, python-2.7, clipboard, pywin32

I am trying to copy an image file to windows clipboard using my code and paste it manually in any folder in windows explorer. I am using **Windows 8 64-bit** laptop, running **Python 2.7** and **pywin32-218** for win32 APIs.

I managed to paste my file in Wordpad application. But, i cannot paste inside windows explorer. The Paste menu is disabled. Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
from win32api import *
from win32clipboard import *
import time
import pythoncom
import struct
from pywin32_testutil import str2bytes

import ctypes
msvcrt = ctypes.cdll.msvcrt
kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32

ret_stg=None
GMEM_MOVEABLE = 0x0002

def set_clipboard(content):
    ret_stg = pythoncom.STGMEDIUM()
    fname_buf=str2bytes(content)

    fname_ba=bytearray(fname_buf)
    fname_ba.append('\0')
    fname_ba.append('\0')

    fmt="lllll%ss" %len(fname_ba)
    df=struct.pack(fmt, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, str(fname_ba))
    ret_stg.set(pythoncom.TYMED_HGLOBAL, df)

    try:
        OpenClipboard()
    except:
        print "open failed, exception=%s"%FormatMessage(GetLastError())
    else: 
        try:
            SetClipboardData(CF_HDROP, ret_stg.data)
        except:
            print "set failed, exception = %s"%FormatMessage(GetLastError())
        finally:
            CloseClipboard()

def get_clipboard():
    try:
        OpenClipboard()
    except:
        print "open failed, exception=%s"%FormatMessage(GetLastError())
    else:   
        if(IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_HDROP)):
            handle = GetClipboardDataHandle(CF_HDROP)
            file_cnt = DragQueryFile(handle)
            print "file count = %ld"%file_cnt
            for i in range(0,file_cnt):
                file_path = DragQueryFile(handle, i)
                print "file name = %s"%file_path
        elif(IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_UNICODETEXT)):
            print "CF_UNICODETEXT content"
            clip_data = GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT)
            print "*** content = %s ***"%clip_data
        else:
            print "unsupported clipboard format"
    finally:
            CloseClipboard()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file1 = "E:\\pics\\ferrari.jpg"
    set_clipboard(file1)
    time.sleep(1)
    get_clipboard()
```

**Update:** For some strange reasons, the above code works fine in Windows 7 64 bit. I am able to paste my file in Wordpad as well as Explorer window.

Comment: If you already know the image filename, why not just `CopyFile` it to the correct folder?

Comment: Thanks for your idea. But my intention is to paste the file in any preferred folder just like default paste operation

Answer (score 0):

the problem may be that the memory that you pass to the clipboard has to be retreived by using GlobalAlloc, has to be locked, written, unlocked and to be passed.

look at the code on this link:

http://www.c-plusplus.de/forum/251309-full

i am not totally sure how to translates this into python or even if this is internally already done

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Using `GlobalAlloc` had no effect in my case. Windows 8 Explorer still does not show the Paste menu